# Doctrine2 how to select object if it is in array list (simpliest way)?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

My question is how to select an object from entity if it is in given array lsit ?
I would use `in` statement when building my query but how to do it with builder ?

for example i have something like this:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
        $query
                ->select('a, c')
                ->from('ApplicationsBundle:Application', 'a', 'a.Name')
                ->innerJoin('a.categories', 'c');

        $results = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

it gives me an array with keys = app name and elements categories of that app
its two tables apllications and categories reletaed n:m

Closer look to my problem:
i need something similar couse i have app lsit (name parametr) from a difrent source and i want to display in categories.
For example:

```
Category 1:
app1, app2, app3
Category 2:
app3, app4
Other (no category):
app5
```

Do you have any idea to do it as simple as possible ?

Comment: will it works correct adding this line `->where($query->expr()->in('a.Name', $appNames));`

Comment: Did you try to select from your categories and join your applications? Then you'll have a liste of categories with the related applications (if your mapping is bidirectional)

Comment: ok it also works but how to know which apps got category and which not ? to display in the end also that without category ?

Comment: Since you're using an innerJoin i would create a category named "Other" for example to store every applications without category

Comment: the problem is that i can not do it.
cous i dont manage new apps adding and stuff like that.